# value of hidden element is not changed

Tags: angular, cypress, hidden, e2e

I have the following checkbox element

```
<div _ngcontent-qcu-c225="" class="checkbox-section terms-of-sale"><div _ngcontent-qcu-c225="" class="checkbox-wrapper"><ion-checkbox _ngcontent-qcu-c225="" data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox" formcontrolname="acceptTermsOfSale" data-name="cta_confirmtermsofsale" class="checkbox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ios interactive hydrated ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-invalid" aria-checked="false" role="checkbox"><input type="hidden" class="aux-input" name="ion-cb-0" value=""></ion-checkbox></div><div _ngcontent-qcu-c225="" class="legal"><span _ngcontent-qcu-c225="" class="valid"><p _ngcontent-qcu-c225=""> I accept the <a _ngcontent-qcu-c225="" data-cy="external-terms-of-sale-link" target="_blank" class="link">Terms of Sale</a></p></span></div></div>
```

I have tried to click the check box using

```
    cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"]:last input').should('exist').click({force: true, multiple: true});

    cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"] input').should('exist').click({force: true, multiple: true});

    cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"]').check()
```

neither one has worked , the element does not get clicked, the value dose not change

I am using cypess 7 with macos. the browser is chrome.

EDIT: On the page I have a single checkbox "Terms of sale" which needs to be clicked

Comment: If I assume correctly you have multiple checkbox on your page and you want to select one particular checkbox ?

Comment: What is returned with a simple `cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"]')`?

Answer (score 2):

Two thing with ionic checkbox, there's heavy use of shadow DOM so add the switch to `cypress.json`

```js
{
  "includeShadowDom": true
}
```

The checkbox is implemented with `<input type="hidden" >` which is unusual and it fools Cypress into thinking it's not a checkbox, so you have to use `.click()` instead of `.check()`

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"])
  .find('input')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', '')  // empty on page load

cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"])
  .click({force:true})   // {force:true} if it's hidden, but try without first

cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"])
  .find('input')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'on')  // switched to "on"
```

Ref: [End-to-end Testing Mobile Apps with Ionic and Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/07/08/end-to-end-testing-mobile-apps-with-ionic-and-cypress/)

Comment: DId not work. I am getting cy.check() can only be called on :checkbox and :radio. I updated the post to include the whole html element. please referes

Comment: @FarFarAway - you are still using `check()`? See above, you should `click()` not `check()`.

Comment: If it's hidden, you may need `.click({force:true})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` with the combination of text and selector.

```js
cy.contains('[data-name="cta_confirmtermsofsale"]', 'Terms of sale')
  .should('exist')
  .click()
```

or with `{force: true}`

```js
cy.contains('[data-name="cta_confirmtermsofsale"]', 'Terms of sale')
  .should('exist')
  .click({force: true})
```

Comment: this did not work.

Comment: I updated the answer with `exist`, please try with that. If that also doesn't work please add the error screenshot.

Comment: It did not work also. also this cy.contains('[data-name="cta_confirmtermsofsale"]')
  .should('exist')
  .click() did not work. the error is expected to find element, but never did

Comment: Without seeing the error or more information about your DOM, I won't be able to debug more. I am assuming that the checkbox has a label of `Terms of sale` text and that the checkbox is not inside an iframe.

Comment: I have included the complete HTML element on my original question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"] input').should('include.text', 'Terms of sale')
```

or

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="terms-of-sale-checkbox"] input').invoke('text').then(text) => {
  expect(text).contains('Terms of sale')
}
```

it might help you.